# refile to -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example with [a context](http://news.yahoo.com/one-killed-five-wounded-shooting-spree-phoenix-suburb-012004313.html):

> (The story was **refiled to** paragraph 12, to say "another person's vehicle" from "the man's vehicle" to make clear the person carjacked was not the student who was shot)

*Refile* literally means *to file again* (meaning, to take a bunch of documents and put them in an index card file cabinet or something similar to that) as in *let's refile these files because they have been updated*, but I'm not really sure what they mean by *refiled to paragraph 12* in the sentence above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a jargon usage. In the US since about 1900 newspaper reporters have been said to *file* a story when they turn it in to the editor, whether as a typescript or a telephone or telegraph report.

Here, *refile* signifies that the reporters rewrote that part of the story.